# The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}\mbox{sech}\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, special-functions

Does anyone have a proof that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}\mbox{sech}\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{8}$$

Comment: Do you have any context you can provide?

Comment: This would imply that the solution $u(x,y)$ of the Laplace equation $\Delta u=0$ on the unit square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ with boundary condition: $u(x,1)=1, u(x,0)=0, u(0,y)=0, u(1,y)=0$ is 1/4 at the center $(1/2,1/2)$.

Comment: Since it's obvious that $u(1/2,1/2) =1/4$ can you work backwards to get the sum?

Comment: You'll want to look up papers by Zucker and Ling on series of hyperbolic functions. The usual proofs proceed through the use of Jacobi theta functions.

Comment: I think @kiwi makes sense. Using Schwarz Christoffel mapping from unit disc to square of side length 2, and Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: This series is due to Jacobi. See p. 408 of I.J.Zucker's paper "Some infinite series of exponential and hyperbolic functions " SIAM J. Math. Anal. (1984) vol.15, 406-413.

Comment: @TCL, you might want to answer your own question with the stuff from Zucker. :)

Comment: But I don't have a direct proof. I don't have English translation of the work by C. G. J. JACOBI, Fundamenta Nova Theoriae Functionum Ellipticurum, Knigsberg, 1829.

Comment: Alright, but did you check Ling's papers as well? That takes the Weierstrass route, but if memory serves it is a bit more direct.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it.

Answer (score 6):

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2z\cosh(z\pi)}$$

so that the sum in question is half of

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n f\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right) = \sum \operatorname*{Res} (\pi \sec(\pi z)f(z))\text{ at poles of }f$$

$f$ has poles at $0$ and at $b_n = \frac{i(2n+1)}{2}$ for integer $n$.  Then

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0} (\pi \sec(\pi z)f(z)) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=b_n} (\pi \sec(\pi z)f(z)) = -\frac{(-1)^n}{1+2n} \operatorname{sech}\left(\pi \frac{2n+1}{2}\right)$$

Then

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{1+2n} \operatorname{sech}\left(\pi \frac{2n+1}{2}\right)=
-\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{1+2n} \operatorname{sech}\left(\pi \frac{2n+1}{2}\right) + \frac{\pi}{2} \implies\\
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{1+2n} \operatorname{sech}\left(\pi \frac{2n+1}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}
$$

So finally, solving for the sum and dividing by 2:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{1+2n} \operatorname{sech}\left(\pi \frac{2n+1}{2}\right) = 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1} \operatorname{sech}\left(\pi \frac{2n-1}{2}\right)
=\frac{\pi}{8}$$

Comment: I don't understand the first equality in your answer. Why are both sides equal? Are you integrating over some contour?

Comment: @TCL Ah, sorry, I thought you were familiar with this formula.  It is derived like the formula on page 76 [here](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/complex-analysis/complex_analysis_part7.pdf), but $\cot(\pi z)$ is replaced with $\sec (\pi z)$.

Comment: Your argument is correct provided the contour integral of $\pi\sec(\pi z)f(z)$ over the boundary of the square $[-n,n]\times [-n,n]$ approaches 0 as $n\to\infty$. I think that should be ok.